# How do I add a condition to ElasticSearch Aggregation (min/max)?

Tags: php, elasticsearch, phalcon, nosql-aggregation

I want to query to my Elastic-Search to get minimum price of values which have only positive value. My prices can also be zero and -1; so I don't want my min-aggregation to return 0 or -1. I know that I should add a script to the query (or filter), but I don't know how. My current code:

```
public function minPriceAggregation($minName, $field = 'price')
    {
        if ($field) {
            $this->aggregation[$minName] = [
                'min' => [
                    'field' => $field
                ]
            ];
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

This query always returns -1; I want to ignore the values < 0 and only have the minimum in my positive values.

Something like:

```
public function minPriceAggregation($minName, $field = 'price')
    {
        if ($field) {
            $this->aggregation[$minName] = [
                'min' => [
                    'field' => $field,
                    'script' => [
                        'source' => 'return _value > 0 ?: _value' //What's the correct script here??
                    ]
                ]
            ];
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public function minPriceAggregation($minName, $field = 'price')
    {
        if ($field) {
            $this->aggregation[$minName] = [
                'min' => [
                    'script' => [
                        'source' => 'return Math.max(0, doc["price"].value)'
                    ]
                ]
            ];
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Math.max always returns 0 because my minimum value is -1. Suppose I have these values: [-1, 0, 5, 10, 15, ....]. I want my function to return 5; but your answer always returns 0 in my case. Is there any better option?

Comment: `Math.max(0, -1) = 0`, `Math.max(0, 5) = 5`. Can you show a sample document, please?

Comment: As I said I have price values between -1 and X. I want a query to ignore the values < 0 and only returns the minimum value of the positive prices. In your solution doc["price"].value is always -1; so  Math.max(0, doc["price"].value) always returns 0.

Comment: Is there any way to ignore the negative values first and after that pass it to min?

Comment: Ok, then you simply need a query part that excludes documents with negative prices

Comment: Can you show me how I can merge query part with my code?

Comment: You should modify the `$this->query` part